# How to use DateTime in Slick2.0?

Tags: scala, jodatime, slick, slick-2.0

I want to use `DateTime` in Slick 2.0 model. I use jodatime:

I added the dependencies in `Build.scala`:

```
   "joda-time" % "joda-time"    % "2.3",
   "org.joda"  % "joda-convert" % "1.6"
```

I then do:

```
 class Comment(tag:Tag) extends Table[(Long, Int, Int, String, Int, DateTime)](tag,"Comment"){
  def id=column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def rate=column[Int]("rate")
  def sub=column[Int]("subject")
  def content=column[Int]("cotent")
  def user_ID=column[Int]("user")
  def time=column[DateTime]("time")   //-----------an error here
  def * = (id, rate,sub, content, user_ID, time)
}
```

the error is:

```
 could not find implicit value for parameter tm: scala.slick.ast.TypedType[org.joda.time.LocalDate]
```

I added joda-convert jar but it doesn't seems to work. How to add a DateTime in a Slick model class?

Comment: How does the accepted solution helps you? Because, I am facing the same issue. But the below solution didn't solve my issue. Can you please help me to fix the issue? Can you please look at the issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/37076027/1584121. Thanks :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper or you must create your own type mapper

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 14):

The other answer mentioned the library, but if you want to just create your own mapper and have it in the class, this is one such example:

```
implicit def dateTime =
    MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
      dt => new Timestamp(dt.getMillis),
      ts => new DateTime(ts.getTime)
    )
```

Source: Paul Coghlan (@paulcoghlan)'s comment on Gist here https://gist.github.com/dragisak/4756344#comment-1211671

Comment: Considering simplicity this should be the better answer.