# Play framework 2.5 - scala oauth2 provider issue

Tags: mysql, scala, oauth-2.0, playframework-2.5

**WHAT I DID:**

I am trying to implement oauth2 provider using Play framework. I am using the "scala-oauth2-provider" sample to do this. ["https://github.com/nulab/scala-oauth2-provider"](https://github.com/nulab/scala-oauth2-provider)

I have listed the version that I used in my application:

> Play -- 2.5
>
> database -- Mysql 5.1.22

**ISSUE:**

> **AuthCode.scala:19:** could not find implicit value for parameter tm:
>   scala.slick.ast.TypedType[org.joda.time.DateTime] [error]   def
>   createdAt = columnDateTime

**Code Snippet:**

```
import java.util.UUID
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._

case class AuthCode(authorizationCode: String, userGuid: UUID, redirectUri: Option[String], createdAt: DateTime, scope: Option[String], clientId: Option[String], expiresIn: Int)

class AuthCodes(tag: Tag) extends Table[AuthCode](tag, "auth_codes") {
  def authorizationCode = column[String]("authorization_code", O.PrimaryKey)
  def userGuid = column[UUID]("user_guid")
  def redirectUri = column[Option[String]]("redirect_uri")
  def createdAt = column[DateTime]("created_at")
  def scope = column[Option[String]]("scope")
  def clientId = column[Option[String]]("client_id")
  def expiresIn = column[Int]("expires_in")
  def * = (authorizationCode, userGuid, redirectUri, createdAt, scope, clientId, expiresIn) <> (AuthCode.tupled, AuthCode.unapply)
}
```

How do I fix this issue? Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Note: I have also tried the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/22578950/1584121. But I am getting same issue :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use DateTime in Slick2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578501/how-to-use-datetime-in-slick2-0)

Comment: @cchantep No. That didn't solve my issue. I have applied the two solution. But got the same issue.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by adding the below import statement. 
import com.github.tototoshi.slick.MySQLJodaSupport._

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look into the sample project, but I used the solution available through https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper. Hopefully you can apply this to your code. I am using Scala 2.11.8 with Slick 3.1.1, and therefore use slick-joda-mapper 2.2.0. If you are using different versions of Scala and/or Slick, you might have to select a different version of slick-joda-mapper.

First add the required dependencies to your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.1",
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
    "com.github.tototoshi" %% "slick-joda-mapper" % "2.2.0",
    "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.7",
    "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.7"
)
```

In your Scala source file, use the following imports:

```
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import com.github.tototoshi.slick.MySQLJodaSupport._
import org.joda.time.DateTime
```

You can then use a `DateTime` object simply in Slick queries.